# React Simple Dropdown not working

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a react simple dropdown following the instructions from this website: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-dropdown

This is the code for the dropdown component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Dropdown.css';
var Dropdown = require('react-simple-dropdown');
var DropdownTrigger = Dropdown.DropdownTrigger;
var DropdownContent = Dropdown.DropdownContent;

class Menu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Dropdown>
          <DropdownTrigger>Profile</DropdownTrigger>
          <DropdownContent>
              <img src="avatar.jpg" /> Username
              <ul>
                  <li>
                      <a href="/profile">Profile</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="/favorites">Favorites</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="/logout">Log Out</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </DropdownContent>
      </Dropdown>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

When I import the Menu component using `import Menu from '../Dropdown/Menu'` and add the component to App.js I get the following error:

**"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
Check the render method of `Menu`."**

Could you please help with this?

Thanks,
Emir Kobaslic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like require statement is not importing default export from react-simple-dropdown, because of mixing of ES6 import and require,
so you have to import Dropdown, DropdownTrigger &  DropdownContent like below:

```
import Dropdown, { DropdownTrigger, DropdownContent} from 'react-simple-dropdown';
```

so your code will be :

```
import React from 'react';
import Dropdown, { DropdownTrigger, DropdownContent} from 'react-simple-dropdown';

class Menu extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Dropdown>
            <DropdownTrigger>Profile</DropdownTrigger>
            <DropdownContent>
                <img src="avatar.jpg" /> Username
          <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/profile">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/favorites">Favorites</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/logout">Log Out</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </DropdownContent>
        </Dropdown>
    );
}
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: Getting following error: Uncaught TypeError: can't assign to property "current" on "trigger": not an object